# Android : dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory

Tags: android

Here I'm downloading images from server one by one .Getting error of dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 31961104-byte allocation while run the app and is crashed in middle .Some time images download sometime not.But i want add images in Listview from download..

Here is my download code

```
   private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {

            final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

                //check 200 OK for success
                final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode +
                            " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                    return null;
                }
                final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    try {
                        // getting contents from the stream
                        inputStream = entity.getContent();

                        // decoding stream data back into image Bitmap that android understands
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inSampleSize = 1;
                        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
                       // final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                        File file = new File(newFolder, imageName);

                        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                        try
                        {
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();
                            int imagenObtenidaW = bitmap.getWidth();
                            int imagenObtenidaH = bitmap.getHeight();
                            Log.e("imagenObtenidaW " ," = +" + imagenObtenidaW + " imagenObtenidaH = " + imagenObtenidaH);

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }

                        return bitmap;
                    } finally {
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            inputStream.close();
                        }
                        entity.consumeContent();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // You Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException
                getRequest.abort();
                Log.e("ImageDownloader", "Something went wrong while" +
                        " retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

    here is my code form download in the same Activity.

    if (imageName.endsWith(png_Pattern) || imageName.endsWith(jpg_pattern) || imageName.endsWith(bmp_pattern) || imageName.endsWith(gif_pattern) || imageName.endsWith(jpeg_pattern))
                        {

                            str_DownLoadUrl = namespace + "/DownloadFile/FileName/" + imageName;
                            Log.e("@@@@@", "str_DownLoadUrl  = " + str_DownLoadUrl);
                            //download_PngFile(str_DownLoadUrl);
                            downloadBitmap(str_DownLoadUrl);
                            strDownLoadStatus = "1";
                            dbhelper.update_DownLoadStatus(imageName, strDownLoadStatus);
                        }
                    }
```

Here is my logcat

```
1.414  10598-10601/com.example.tazeen.classnkk D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1738K, 57% free 15379K/35335K, paused 5ms+7ms
10-13 14:52:11.963  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 64K, 57% free 15377K/35335K, paused 95ms
10-13 14:52:11.963  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 31961104-byte allocation
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 57% free 15368K/35335K, paused 68ms
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 31961104-byte allocation.
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ "AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=13 RUNNABLE
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x42ad4188 self=0x1edbd8
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=10826 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=1591808
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ | schedstat=( 12449561867 3389288161 878 ) utm=1181 stm=63 core=0
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page.downloadBitmap(AllPosts_Page.java:1220)
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page.getDoenLoaddata(AllPosts_Page.java:738)
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$GetgetDoenLoaddata.doInBackground(AllPosts_Page.java:700)
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$GetgetDoenLoaddata.doInBackground(AllPosts_Page.java:696)
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-13 14:52:12.034  10598-10826/com.example.tazeen.classnkk I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 10-13 14:52:12.034 10598:0x2a4a D/skia     ]
    --- decoder->decode returned false
```

How to solve this issue.

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" do u set this in Manifest file?

Comment: why don't you use image loading library for adding image in list view?

Comment: adding `android:largerHeap="true"` is not the correct way of managing this problem.

Comment: android:largerHeap="true" Adding this line in Application tag or before application tag

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises when you are downloading images and there is no memory left which was allotted to your app after downloading some images. There are various Image Loading Libraries which make your work easier : [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/), [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) etc.

1. I would suggest you to checkout **Image Management Library by Facebook** that is [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) that is pretty awesome and mature as compared to other Image Loading Library.
2. Fresco has `SimpleDraweeView` as custom image view which supports `Rounded Corners and Circles` [link](http://frescolib.org/docs/rounded-corners-and-circles.html#_) and supports Animated(.gif, .webp) as well as Normal Images(.jpg, .png).
3. Fresco handles all the things caching of images with 3 Tier architecture ( `BITMAP_MEMORY_CACHE`, `ENCODED_MEMORY_CACHE` and `DISK_CACHE`). It also reduces OOM(Out Of Memory) issues. When image in a view goes out of screen it automatically recycles the bitmap, hence releasing the memory.

You Can increase the Memory allotted to your application by adding `android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest.

**Note :** Increasing `heap` for your application doesn't considered to be a ideal solution.

Here's the extract from google that explains it,

> However, the ability to request a large heap is intended only for a
>   small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such
>   as a large photo editing app). Never request a large heap simply
>   because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix—you should
>   use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being
>   allocated and why it must be retained. Yet, even when you're confident
>   your app can justify the large heap, you should avoid requesting it to
>   whatever extent possible. Using the extra memory will increasingly be
>   to the detriment of the overall user experience because garbage
>   collection will take longer and system performance may be slower when
>   task switching or performing other common operations.

here's the complete link of the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html